# База данных как шина связи между экземплярами приложения

Tags: веб-программирование, postgresql, архитектура, триггер

У меня в голове крутится один интересный проект и сразу появилось несколько теоретических вопросов.
Проект - это распределенная CMS.

**Вводные:**

1. Есть база данных (postgresql)
2. Есть множество экземпляров этой CMS (ноды).
3. Все ноды работают с БД из пункта 1

**Вопрос:**
Собственно встаёт вопрос - как лучше всего организовать синхронизацию нод?
У меня появилась идея сделать это через базу данных.

**Как я это вижу:**
Ноды синхронизируют свое состояние через LISTEN/NOTIFY возможности Postgresql.
К примеру, одна из нод меняет что то в базе данных - отрабатывает trigger, который уведомляет об изменениях все ноды.
Ноды в свою очередь реагируют на нотификации от базы данных и обновляют своё состояние.
Так же в базе возможно придется добавить несколько служебных таблиц, к примеру список функционирующих нод и тд.

Но я не уверен что это хороший подход. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Можете предлагать другие варианты - я буду только рад.

Comment: Не, в принципе схема жизнеспособная. Только мне, например, не нравится триггерное уведомление. Прикинь - нода обновляет сотню связных записей в десятке таблиц, и всем полетела сотня уведомлений - во счастье-то... может, пусть триггер только выставляет марк в какой-нить служебной таблице (или голый факт, что что-то поменялось, или, скажем, пишет имя таблицы и штамп времени), на сервере какой-нить эвент по факту появления новых записей в этой таблице уведомляет подписчиков с достаточной регулярностью (скажем, раз в секунду или там 10 секунд), а те, буде надо, по этому сигналу обновляют данные.

Comment: Действительно, сотни уведомлений - такое себе удовольствие.  Ну тут уже да, нужно будет продумать саму механику, что бы оптимизировать кол-во уведомлений и т.д. Главное что вы подтвердили что такая схема жизнеспособна. Подождем еще комментариев)

Comment: Альтернативная схема - все подписчики используют одни и те же таблицы, а номер подписчика (нода) - атрибут в таблицах, по которого нод пишет/фильтрирует свое содержание. Уведомления не нужни. "Один источник правды, [SSOT](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/single-source-of-truth-SSOT)"

Comment: Но при подходе 1 БД <-- N нод и так получается "один источник правды" - это база данных. Вопрос в том, как организовать актуализацию состояния нод, в зависимости от изменения состояния базы данных. Возможно я неправильно вас понял.